# python code order of magnitude faster than compiled C code for simple import statement

Tags: python, c, windows, tensorflow, cpython

I'm baffled by the performance difference of the following two semantically equivalent(?) programs.

Python:

```
#test.py
import time
starttime=time.time()
import tensorflow 
print(f"Import took: {time.time() - starttime}")
```

C using CPython

```
//test.c
#include <Python.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <time.h> 
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    Py_Initialize();
    clock_t t = clock();
    PyObject* pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("tensorflow");
    double time_taken = ((double)clock() - t)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Import took:  %f\n", time_taken);
    return 0;
}
```

Now compare the two:

```
cl.exe /I"C:\Program Files\Python37\include" test.c
link test.obj python37.lib /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files\Python37\libs"
.\test.exe
```

> 2020-04-17 13:00:51.598550: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_100.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_100.dll not found
>   2020-04-17 13:00:51.606296: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
>
> **Import took: 23.160523891448975**

```
python test.py
```

> 2020-04-17 13:01:19.525648: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_100.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_100.dll not found
>   2020-04-17 13:01:19.530726: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
>
> **Import took: 2.3172824382781982**

Not that it should matter much but my tensorflow version is 1.15
Why is the python VM code so much faster than the compiled CPython code?
Does the python vm add some magic that PyImport_ImportModule doesn't?

Comment: C took almost exactly 10x. Did you time it with a stopwatch to be sure? Did python use the `.py` or `.pyc` [the pre-compiled object version]? How long did python run (ie. compile) before running the actual script?

Comment: The difference isn't always as stark, but the .exe is consistenly much slower than the python code. I checked in the tensorflow folder and there don't seem to be any new .pyc files that mightve given either run an advantage. The script runs pretty much instantly, compilation time is unnoticable.

Comment: sorry if that's silly because I never used cpython at all but could it be that `PyImport_ImportModule("tensorflow")` has to do more work because it is a python module and is now used in c?

Comment: CPython is the python reference implementation in C, so it really IS python. I assumed that the python interpreter translates import statements to PyImport_ImportModule but obviously there is something else going on

Comment: Try compiling your C code with `/Ox` Note capital letter O, not zero

Comment: Import took:18.814000. Negligible improvement :)

Comment: I'm suspicious of the fact that you're timing, not the time it takes to do some actual computation work, but the time it takes to import a module.  Also you're importing a module with an import error involved.  It seems to me that either of these could make a huge difference — perhaps one way is trying harder to find the missing cudart64_100.dll dependency, or perhaps one way has a faster way of knowing that it's not there, and giving up.  It seems to me what you really want to be timing is the computations you're *doing* with the tensorflow module once it's loaded.

Answer (score 0):

PyImport_ImportModule is part of the C ABI, which means it can have performance penalty: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/stable.html#stable-abi-list

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30989990)